# ExceptionInInitializerError & Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

Tags: android, handler, toast

1.I want to Toast in a Thread

2.and i have set `Looper.getMainLooper()`

But it still crash
i know can use `activity.runOnUiThread` solve this problem
but i want to find another method to solve, just change `ToastUtil`.

Please, Thanks in advance

```
public class ToastUtil {

private static Toast toast = Toast.makeText(MainApplication.getApp(),"",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
private static Toast scrollToast = Toast.makeText(MainApplication.getApp(),"",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

public static void show(final String src) {
    if (StringUtils.isEmpty(src)) {
        return;
    }
    r.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            toast.setText(src);
            toast.show();
        }
    });
    Logger.d("Toast", src);
}

public static void show(int resId) {
    final String src;
    src = MainApplication.getApp().getResources().getString(resId);
    if (StringUtils.isEmpty(src)) {
        return;
    }
    r.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            toast.setText(src);
            toast.show();
        }
    });
}

public static void showScrollToast(final String src) {
    final View toastRoot = LayoutInflater.from(MainApplication.getApp()).inflate(R.layout.widget_view_toast, null);
    MyTextView textView = (MyTextView) toastRoot.findViewById(R.id.scroll_toast);
    textView.setText(src);
    r.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            scrollToast.setGravity(Gravity.FILL_HORIZONTAL | Gravity.TOP, 0, DisplayMetricsTools.dp2px(50));
            scrollToast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            scrollToast.setView(toastRoot);
            scrollToast.show();
        }
    });

}

private static Handler r = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());}
```

crash log:

```
 java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
                                                 at com.utils.ToastUtil.show(ToastUtil.java:24)
                                                 at com.utils.ErrorInfo.showError(ErrorInfo.java:43)
                                                 at com.integration.CreateBoardActivity.allotModerators(CreateBoardActivity.java:392)
                                                 at com.integration.CreateBoardActivity.access$900(CreateBoardActivity.java:72)
                                                 at com.duodian.morespace.integration.CreateBoardActivity$10.run(CreateBoardActivity.java:371)
                                                 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
                                              Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
                                                 at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:200)
                                                 at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:114)
                                                 at android.widget.Toast$TN$2.<init>(Toast.java:336)
                                                 at android.widget.Toast$TN.<init>(Toast.java:336)
                                                 at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:103)
                                                 at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:256)
                                                 at com.utils.ToastUtil.<clinit>(ToastUtil.java:20)
                                                 at com.utils.ToastUtil.show(ToastUtil.java:24) 
                                                 at com.utils.ErrorInfo.showError(ErrorInfo.java:43) 
                                                 at com.integration.CreateBoardActivity.allotModerators(CreateBoardActivity.java:392) 
                                                 at com.integration.CreateBoardActivity.access$900(CreateBoardActivity.java:72) 
                                                 at com.integration.CreateBoardActivity$10.run(CreateBoardActivity.java:371) 
                                                 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

Comment: You should pass the Activity context to show a Toast in an external class. In this way you can inherit the style from the Activity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not the `Handler` inside your `ToastUtil` but **the `Handler` inside `Toast`**.

An instance of `TN` is created in the constructor of `Toast`.

```
public Toast(Context context) {
    mContext = context;
    mTN = new TN();
    ......
}
```

And `TN` contains a member field which is a handler.

```
private static class TN extends ITransientNotification.Stub {
    ......
    final Handler mHandler = new Handler();  
    ......
}
```

As you use `ToastUtil` in a normal Thread for the first time, the handler of that `TN` will be initialized in that thread without a looper which causes the crash.

You should either use `ToastUtil` in the main thread or in a thread which has a looper.

There is a solution by just changing `ToastUtil`.

Don't make the `toast` or `scrollToast` **static** instead instantiating them in method `show` or `showScrollToast`. e.g.

```
public static void show(final String src) {
    if (StringUtils.isEmpty(src)) {
        return;
    }
    r.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(MainApplication.getApp(),"",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.setText(src);
            toast.show();
       }
    });
    Logger.d("Toast", src);
}
```

Comment: Thx ! This is the crux of the problem !

Answer (score 0):

I think that using the utility in this way would be better:

```
public class ToastUtil {
    //if you don't care about the toast style you can pass the Application
    //context instead of the Activity one
    public static void show(Context context, @StringRes int stringRes) {
        String message = context.getResources().getString(stringRes);
        Toast.makeText(context, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Logger.d("Toast", message);
    }
}
```

And then use this like this:

```
ToastUtil.show(context, R.string.my_message);
```

If you want to completely ignore the Activity style, you should add a constructor to the class passing the Application, then you can call every static method without passing the context over and over. (or in alternative you could initialize this Utility in a BaseActivity which every Activity extends)